# Keyboard Shortcuts not working until restarting mate-settings-daemon on startup

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mate, 22.04, gnome-settings-daemon

I've been having issues with keyboard shortcuts for volume keys. They work when I manually set new shortcuts but stop working after reboot or new session.

As a workaround I can get them working by running at startup:

```
killall mate-settings-daemon && mate-settings-daemon
```

Afterwards the keys function correctly so I've simply created a custom startup script.

Does anyone know the cause of this or how I might permanently fix this issue? I was wondering if it is a conflict between the mate-settings-daemon and the gnome-settings-daemon.

Comment: tag MATE version perhaps